# How can I label internal nodes with SHaLRT and UFBoot values using ggtree?

Tags: r, phylogeny, ggtree

I am trying to construct a phylogenomic tree in `ggtree`, and would like to present a few different versions. The tree was constructed using `IQTree`, and the `UFBoot` and `SHaLRT` values are stored as a list of characters called "node.label".

I have constructed a cladogram, and colored the node tips based on which of three species categories the sequences belong to. However, I am unable to do the following:

1. I would like to label the internal nodes with the corresponding UFBoot/SHaLRT (BS) values (e.g. 97/100).
2. If possible, I would also like to make a second version in which I modify nodes to indicate 3 levels:

e.g. hollow circle = UFBoot/SHaLRT below threshold, gray circle= 1 test passed, black circle = both tests passed.

So far I have tried making a dataframe with all the BS values and trying:

```r
  geom_text2(aes(subset=!isTip, label=node), hjust=-.3) + 
     # Label with internal node numbers
```

But I always get an error saying the lengths of the labels and nodes don't match.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that we can replicate the error.